# Java OOPS Parking Lot example Design

Tags: java, oop

Help me in understanding the power of OOPS in this famous [Parking Lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764933/amazon-interview-question-design-an-oo-parking-lot) example.
I read this post yesterday trying to figure out perfect lower level design.

ParkingLot
- ParkingLot has ParkingSpaces ( List of ParkingSpaces)
- exit()
- entrance()
- Update()
- int capacity

ParkingSpace
 -long id
 -String type (2 wheeler, 4 wheeler etc)
 -Vehicle (has Vechicle Reference)

Vehicle (interface- any kind of vehicle (two wheeler, four wheeler)
 - park() 
 - Unpark() 
  abstract methods
 - has reference of ParkingLot and ParkingSpace

Car,Truck different kind of vehicles implements Vehicle.

Is there anything am I missing here...is there any design pattern I need to follow here..
How are we achieving polymorphism in this example.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to figure out... are you trying to design a parking lot in terms of objects? Is this homework?

Comment: classes, interfaces, methods, variables and how OOPS concepts helps in designing this application.

Comment: It's nice to accept the answer when they helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object-oriented programming helps in this situation because your vehicle interface allows you to define similar actions for many different vehicles without having to write those methods/functions for each individual type of vehicle.

It sounds like you've got a pretty good handle on your classes (ParkingLot, ParkingSpace, Car, Truck) and your interface (Vehicle). If different types of parking spaces had different fields, you could consider a ParkingSpace interface which is then implemented by MotorcycleSpace, CompactSpace, etc. but how you have it now isn't incorrect. Polymorphism comes in as well with your interface.

EDIT: With regard to composition, you have a ParkingLot that has ParkingSpaces. If your Vehicle class had Wheels or Options or some other subclass, that would be additional composition.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I have one question, how composition and aggregation work here..